# Android : Create a file in /data/local/tmp from an automated test

Tags: android, linux, file-permissions, android-uiautomator

**Goal:**
Taking a screenshot during an automated test on a device. Pull the screenshot file using adb once the test is done.

**Context:**

I'm currently trying to write automated tests to take snapshots of the device screen. Using [UiDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html) to navigate, I would like  to take a screenshot in the middle of a test. UiDevice has a method [takeScreenshot](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#takeScreenshot(java.io.File,%20float,%20int)) that I call when I would like to take a snapshot.

After some investigation, I realised that the class responsible to write the image into file [UiAutomatorBridge](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/com/android/uiautomator/core/UiAutomatorBridge.java#UiAutomatorBridge.takeScreenshot%28java.io.File%2Cint%29) catches an Exception :

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /data/local/tmp/screenshots/screen2.png: open failed: EACCES
>   (Permission denied)

Using [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html), I created the file and set all permissions to all users.

```
adb shell touch /data/local/tmp/screenshots/screen1.png
adb shell chmod 777 /data/local/tmp/screenshots
```

Once done, I can take a screenshot with :

```
@Test
public void takeSnapShot() {
    String filename = "/data/local/tmp/screenshots/screen1.png";
    File file = new File(filename);
    assertEquals(true, mDevice.takeScreenshot(file));
}
```

**Problem :**

I would like to be able to create a file directly while the test is executing, without the need of using adb. 
I tried to create a file directly from Java using [createNewFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()).

```
try {
     file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I get an IOException

> java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Has anyone an idea of what is going on ? I'm quite new to Linux, so don't hesitate to suggest something even if it seems obvious to you ;)

Should I post this on [superuser](https://superuser.com/) instead ?

**EDIT**

The directory */data* has these permissions

```
drwxrwx--x system   system            2016-01-14 14:03 data
```

I can't list the content of */data*, which makes me believe the user "shell" doesn't belong to the group "system". I can't list the content of */data/local* neither.

However, the */data/local/tmp* is owned by "shell".

```
drwxrwx--x shell    shell             2016-01-14 12:20 . (tmp)
```

*/data/local/tmp* gives +x permission to all users.

Finally, the directory "screenshots" belongs to shell with permissions 777.

```
drwxrwxrwx shell    shell             2016-01-14 11:46 screenshots
```

To my understanding,  any user should be able to access */data/local/tmp/screenshots*

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to create an empty file that will be overridden by the snapshot image later. You just need to make sure that the directory you specify for the output is writable by the process.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not a Linux expert. I thought that setting directory permissions to 777  was enough to allow users to add file into it. Is it incorrect ? Do you know all the conditions required for a user to be allowed to create a file in a directory ?

Comment: that is correct, but you created the file. I think you should chmod the directory. But you also need to make sure that all the parent directories are have also r+x for the user. /data /data/local /data/local/tmp /data/local/tmp/screenshots

Comment: I edited my post to give you more information. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Can you try one more thing: the code that you want to run doesn't run under user shell I guess. Let's try to figure it out. Let's say create an empty file shomewhere (no idea where) and see it with ls.

Comment: I already tried to write files in the SDCard, but without any success. I added the permissions into the Manifest under src/androidTest. 
Basically, I'm trying to write into a file during the test and access this data through adb.

Comment: Dis you try using File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); instead of hardcoded path? What path does it give to you?

Comment: Yes, but the result was weird. During test, getExternalStorageDirectory returns "/storage/emulated/0" . A directory that doesn't seem to exist on the actual device. And I got an IOException anyway (java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied))

Comment: It is ok that it gives a different path on each device, that's it's purpose :) So did you try to writhe to that directory during the test or only on the actual device?

Comment: I tried to write to a file in this directory during the test. Which resulted in an exception (permission denied). 
And when I browse the device file system (with adb shell), I can't find the directory named "/storage/emulated/0". The only directory seems to be "/storage/emulated/legacy". 
And if I try to write to "/storage/emulated/legacy" during test, I get the same Exception (java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied))

Comment: Anyway. Thank you for your help. I'll try to find a workaround.

Comment: have alook at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/tradefederation/+/b0705dd84e5d6599bb89c673255ef06d1c18dfe7/tests/src/com/android/tradefed/device/TestDeviceStressTest.java And please update us if you find a solution :)

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a look. For now my workaround is to run my test with a  script. At the beginning of the script, I write settings into a file in the folder /data/local/tmp/screenshots on the device(phone). Then I read the settings at the beginning of the test (@Before annotation). In my script, I run the Tests using adb am instrument commands http://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html.

Comment: I finally found a more convenient way to do that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving under */data/local/tmp/*, use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. 
You need a read/write permission to do that. You have to add these two lines into the **Manifest of the application** ! (I tried to add those lines into the /androidTest/Manifest.xml file, but it has no effects).

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

While it solves the problem of finding a common directory to save/read screenshots, it brings a new one as well.

Having to add these 2 permissions isn't a big deal if you already had them. But if you don't want to ask the user for those permissions, you have to add/remove these lines every time you test/sign your application, which is far from ideal.

**EDIT :**

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172608/testing-permissions-and-an-android-apps-manifest-file), someone proposed to make use of the build differentials (debug, release) to have two different Manifests.

In the end, I have 3 Manifests :

- Release Manifest (without external read/write permissions)
- Debug Manifest (with external read/write permissions)
- AndroidTest Manifest for

> tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18"

Comment: you can add these 2 lines in the debug manifest only: src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml